# Sprint Boot Data JPA: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Set<javax.persistence.EntityManager>' available

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am unable to get started with `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. I've created a simple Spring Boot app following [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/), but with Hibernate and related config.

**build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    // Spring stuff
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.5.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc'
    // Jackson
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:+'
    // Postgres
    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:+'
    // Hibernate
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.8.Final'
}
```

Whenever I try to run the app, I end up with the following:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-02-24 16:20:27.710 ERROR 1070 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaContext': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Set<javax.persistence.EntityManager>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at nl.eonics.cdaas.service.Application.main(Application.java:14) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Set<javax.persistence.EntityManager>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1486) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

I have seen [this bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1005) (which is reportedly fixed as of 1.10.7) but downgrading `spring-data-jpa` to **1.9.x** didn't help, I still got the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.5.1.RELEASE' you will not need compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa' and can you post more code, speacialy the configuration related code.

Comment: Yes I know, I've included `spring-data-jpa` specifically to play about its versions. As for configurations, that's about it, everything is in `build.gradle`.

Comment: Have tried it after removing one of them or by removing hibernate-core jar

Comment: Please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51401850/sessionfactory-not-autowired-even-with-beans-provided?noredirect=1#comment89775136_51401850

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in `hibernate-core`. Removing it from dependencies resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when using Spring Boot 2.0.3-RELEASE with Hibernate/JPA with PostgreSQL 10.
I had the following configuration for JPA:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class DomainConfiguration {

   @Value("${database.password}")
   private String password;

   @Value("${database.url}")
   private String url;

   @Value("${database.username}")
   private String userName;

   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource() {
      DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
      dataSource.setDriverClassName(Driver.class.getCanonicalName());
      dataSource.setUrl(this.url);
      dataSource.setUsername(this.userName);
      dataSource.setPassword(this.password);
      return dataSource;
   }

   @Bean
   @DependsOn("flyway")
   public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

      HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
      vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);

      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
      factory.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
      factory.setPersistenceUnitName("MTH");
      factory.setPackagesToScan("nl.mth.sync.domain");
      factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
      return factory;
   }

   @Bean
   public Flyway flyway(DataSource dataSource) {
      log.debug("--- configurating flyway ---");
      Flyway fly = new Flyway();
      fly.setDataSource(dataSource);
      fly.migrate();
      return fly;
   }

   @Bean
   public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
      JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
      txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
      return txManager;
   }
```

And I fixed the issue by adding the following method:

```
   @Bean
   public EntityManager entityManager(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean) {
      return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.getObject().createEntityManager();
   }
```

Comment: I used almost the same code as you except for the bean you add, and two beans had a different type : I had LocalSessionFactoryBean instead of LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean and HibernateTransactionManager instead of PlatformTransactionManager (even thought the content of the bean methods was the same, it was not working). Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

It can be solved by adding as argument to the notation the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
```

This would be in the main method:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class})
```