# No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Set<javax.persistence.EntityManager>

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-data-jpa

After adding dependency of spring-boot-starter-data-jpa in my pom.xml file. I am getting this error.
I searched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442823/sprint-boot-data-jpa-no-qualifying-bean-of-type-java-util-setjavax-persistenc), it says that removing dependency of hibernate core will resolve this issue. However, the error still exist.

Here is my stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaContext': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Set<javax.persistence.EntityManager>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
at com.netpace.firebase.NetpaceFirebaseNotificationsApplication.main(NetpaceFirebaseNotificationsApplication.java:20) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Set<javax.persistence.EntityManager>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
... 19 common frames omitted
```

Here is my applicationContext.xml file :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=Firebase_Notification" />
    <property name="username" value="sa" />
    <property name="password" value="admin123" />

</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

When I am autowiring sessionFactory in my Class it is throwing this exception. I don't know what I am doing wrong as, I am new to Java spring and configuring things in eclipse is really a mess.

Here is my class where I am using sessionFactory:

```
@Component
public class BaseClass<T> implements IBaseDAO<T> {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
private ErrorResponse error;

@Override
public Object save(T object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.getSession().save(object);
}

@Override
public void remove(T object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.getSession().delete(object);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public T update(T object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return (T) this.getSession().merge(object);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public T findById(long id, Class<?> persistClass) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return (T) this.getSession().get(persistClass, id);
}

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    // sessionFactory = configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory();
    return sessionFactory;
}

public Session getSession() {
    SessionFactory session = getSessionFactory();
    return session.getCurrentSession();

}

@ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handle(RuntimeException ex) {
    error.setCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
    error.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
    return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(error, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

}

}
```

Comment: is this a spring boot project? or you just use that dependency?

Comment: It is a spring boot project.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a custom defined sessionFactory / EntityManager, you would need to turn off spring boot's autoconfiguration in the `application.properties` file:

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=
     org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
   , org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
```

Comment: For those who are still facing this problem: @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, **JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class**})

Comment: @MaximMarkov,Thank you so much,It worked what is the magic done by @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class}) this.Please explain in detail,

Comment: Why it will consider auto configurtion when explicit conversation was mentioned in the application.properties and also in DataSourceConfiguration.java in spring boot+Hibernate Integration

Comment: @MaximMarkov , Thanks a lot. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this issue by updating the spring boot version as shown below (in pom.xml):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

This seems like a bug in spring framework as discussed in here

[Error bootstrapping Spring Data JPA with EntityManagerFactory already semi-initialized](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1005)