# SessionFactory not autowired even with Beans provided

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

Integrating spring boot and hibernate but there is an issue with `SessionFactory` autowiring as it is saying that beans are not provided but `@Bean` is provided in the Configuration class.

Please have a look at the code.

[image: Structure of the project]

Dao layer was not provided yet as i'm having issue with SessionFactory autowiring.

MAIN APPLICATION CLASS

```
package com.ctechm.ctec;

 import java.util.Arrays;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;

import com.ctechm.ctec.service.ServiceImpl;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CtecApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

 @Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;

@Autowired 
Text text;

@Autowired
ServiceImpl serviceImpl;
@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CtecApplication.class);
}

   }
```

`@Autowired` Annotations are provided in the above code and their `@Bean` is defined in the Configuration class.It is working fine for all Autowirings except for SessionFactory.

CONFIGURATION CLASS

```
 package com.ctechm.ctec;

 import java.util.Properties;

 import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
 import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
@Configuration
public class Configuration {

 @Bean
 public Text text() {
    return new Text();
 }


@Bean
public Text texter(){
    return new Text();
}

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scm");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");
        return dataSource;
     }

 @Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    LocalSessionFactoryBean bean=new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
     bean.setDataSource(dataSource());
         properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url","jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scm");      properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"); 
         properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
       properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username","root");
       properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password","password");
       bean.setHibernateProperties(properties);
     return bean;
    }

     }
```

Service class

```
package com.ctechm.ctec.service;

import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;

 import com.ctechm.ctec.service.Service;

@Service   
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {


 }
```

application.properties

```
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scm
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

POM.XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.ctechm</groupId>
<artifactId>ctec</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>ctec</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
    </dependencies>

  <build>
     <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </build>


 </project>
```

When ever i start the console getting error like  this

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaContext': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Set<javax.persistence.EntityManager>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1133) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.ctechm.ctec.CtecApplication.main(CtecApplication.java:33) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Set<javax.persistence.EntityManager>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Please have a look and suggest me what changes need to be done.
One thing was when i remove bean and autowiring of sessionFactory everything was working fine.I tried from all the posts in stackoverflow but was not able to figure out the solution.

Comment: As you can see this is missing *avax.persistence.EntityManager* not session factory. Morover you either configure via @Configuration class or via properties. Why both?

Comment: @Antoniossss,Thank you for the suggestion,But when sessionFactory Bean is removed from the configuration,I'm not getting any error,So,How to fix this?Is that EntityManager required for creating Bean of SessionFactory?

Comment: You are about to use JPA? If so, you don't use SessionManager at all as this is part of Hibernate API.

Comment: As Hibernate, we will be using JPA.so it is Spring boot + Hibernate

Comment: But you either use JPA and Hibernate as implementation or Hibernate. Those are different things. Anyway, check this https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/ . If you are indeed want to use JPA that all you should care about is `EntityManager` and forget about sessions.

Comment: *As Hibernate, we will be using JPA.* You probably wanted to say the other way around - if not, than I don't understand what does that mean.

Comment: We have to Use hibernate in this project,Please suggest a way to fix this

Comment: Please state is is going to be JPA or not.... Using Hibernate != Using JPA

Comment: Yes, we selected JPA dependency

Comment: Then forget about sessions and use entity managers. On how to do this, check official Spring guidence. https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/ you will be able either to use repositories or inject EntityManager whenever you want using autoconfiguration.

Comment: I'm sorry,But please suggest me a way to do with Hibernate.We will be using Typical MVC Pattern and in Dao layer we have to use sessionFactory according to requirement and How to autowire sessionFactory using Beans

Comment: For starters, please note the difference between JPA and Hibernate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sprint Boot Data JPA: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.Set<javax.persistence.EntityManager>' available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442823/sprint-boot-data-jpa-no-qualifying-bean-of-type-java-util-setjavax-persistenc)

Comment: we used to work on spring MVC where hibernate configuration was mentioned in XML file,where beans are provided using <bean/> tags but in Java configuration @Bean is not working with SessionFactory.

Comment: We tried removing hibernate-core but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

From the code you posted it is not clear what you want to achieve here.
Using spring-boot and spring-data you basically can start the app with minimum configuration.

In your case you can skip the Configuration.java and configure the database access using the Common Spring Boot properties which you can add directly in the application.properties file.

application.properties

```
## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/scm?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = spring-test
spring.datasource.password = root


## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Autowiring SessionFactory is not needed, instead you can add a Repository interface which will extend the JpaRepository interface. This interface already has definitions for the basic CRUD operations.
Here is an example of how that should look like.

CtecRepository.java

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import java.util.List;

public interface CtecRepository extends JpaRepository<CtecEntity, String> {

   List<CtecEntity> findByName(String name);
}
```

Than you can Inject your Repository to a Service class and from there you can work with the database.

CtecService.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class CtecService {

@Autowired
private CtecRepository ctecRepository;


public void create() {
    CtecEntity entity = new CtecEntity();
    entity.setName("test name");
    ctecRepository.save(entity);
}


public List<CtecEntity> getAllByName(String name) {
    return ctecRepository.findByName(name);
}
}
```

CtecEntity.java

```
import javax.persistence.Id;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ctec")
public class CtecEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```